# MYSQL selecting elements that contains everything in another query

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a database based around a library system and I am trying to enhance my knowledge of MYSQL querys.
I want to try and list the names of borrowers that have borrowed all of the book titles in the database.

The request that I need to strip down is

```
SELECT b.BorName
FROM Borrower b
JOIN Loan l ON l.BorId = b.BorId
JOIN BookCopy bc ON bc.BcId = l.BcId
JOIN BookTitle bt ON bt.BtId = bc.BtId
```

And I guess I need to use `bt.BtName` which is the name of each book in the query above as well as the sub query `SELECT bt.BtName FROM BookTitle bt` but I don't any words or queries to do this with the entire list.

I need to compare the first table with every row in the second query but am yet to find a way to do so.

Comment: Why do you feel that you need to use `BtName` in the query?

Comment: Well I guess I could use either 'BtName' or 'BtId', Both should have the same result.

Comment: Do you have a column with title in the `BookCopy` as well?

Comment: No, BookCopy just links to the BookTitle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After collecting unique borrower-title combinations (with `DISTINCT`), you can identify those borrowers with the number of booktitles equivalent to the total number of booktitles that exist using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT BorName FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT b.BorName, bt.BtId
  FROM Borrower b
  JOIN Loan l ON l.BorId = b.BorId
  JOIN BookCopy bc ON bc.BcId = l.BcId
  JOIN BookTitle bt ON bt.BtId = bc.BtId
) borrowers_titles
GROUP BY BorName
HAVING Count(*) IN (SELECT Count(*) FROM BookTitle)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
SELECT b.BorName, bt.BtName
FROM loan as l 
LEFT JOIN Borrower as b
   ON l.BorId = b.BorID
LEFT JOIN BookCopy as bc 
   ON bc.BcId = l.BcId
LEFT JOIN BookTitle as bt 
   ON bt.BtId = bc.BtId
GROUP BY b.BorName
```

which gets you all the names and books borrowed, grouped (or ordered by) the borrower`s name. 
Now it sounded like you want the names of the people who borrowed every book in the library? If so:

```
SELECT b.BorName
Borrower as b
WHERE 
   (SELECT count(distinct BtId) FROM BookTitle) = 
        (SELECT count(distinct bc.BcID) FROM BookCopy as bc WHERE bc.BorID = b.BorID)
```